# Query Prompting for Parameter Value

Tags: ms-access

I am attempting to creat a VIEW for my class. I was instructed to make my Access Compatible syntax ANSI 92. I have done that but I keep getting a message saying to:

> "Enter parameter Value for 'JR'."

But it should just be showing any with the `JR` in the field value.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT Student.IDno, LastName, FirstName, Class AS
Junior, Major, GPA
FROM Student, Person
WHERE Student.IDno = Person.IDno
AND Class = “JR”;
```

I also have to include columns from 2-3 different tables, change the titles of two of the columns, and show only the records that have `class = "JR"`.

Any advice on where to start looking for this info would be great.

Thank you.

EDIT: Thank you for the help with that last one. Now I'm trying to change this to be able to pull from multiple tables and I can't seem to figure anything out. When I run this code, it tells me it can't find the table or query. If I run each section alone, it works just fine. I need to pull some info from 4 tables...

```
SELECT Student.IDno, Person.LastName, Person.FirstName, Student.Class, Student.Major, Student.GPA
FROM Student, Person
WHERE Student.IDno = Person.IDno
AND Class = 'JR';
UNION
SELECT Student.IDno, Enrollment.OfferNo, Enrollment.Grade
FROM Student, Enrollment
WHERE Student.IDno = Enrollment.IDno;
```

Comment: Try to use ' instead of " because in this case " means [ ]

Comment: That worked ha ha thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The double-quotes present in your SQL code are *'smart quotes'* or Unicode character [0x201C](http://graphemica.com/%E2%80%9C), as opposed to the standard double-quote, which is Unicode/ASCII character [0x0022](http://graphemica.com/%22).

Hence changing the SQL to either:

```sql
SELECT Student.IDno, LastName, FirstName, Class AS Junior, Major, GPA
FROM Student, Person
WHERE Student.IDno = Person.IDno
AND Class = "JR";
```

or:

```sql
SELECT Student.IDno, LastName, FirstName, Class AS Junior, Major, GPA
FROM Student, Person
WHERE Student.IDno = Person.IDno
AND Class = 'JR';
```

Will solve this.

---

However, I would also **strongly** suggest using an `INNER JOIN` (i.e. ANSI-92 syntax) in place of a cartesian product with join criteria in the `WHERE` clause (ANSI-89 syntax):

```sql
SELECT Student.IDno, LastName, FirstName, Class AS Junior, Major, GPA
FROM Student INNER JOIN Person ON Student.IDno = Person.IDno
WHERE Class = 'JR';
```

It is also advisable to state the table qualifier for each field (e.g. `Person.LastName` or `Student.LastName`) so as to avoid the improper use of reserved words or ambiguity arising from identically named fields in multiple tables.

---

In the code you have added to your question, you are attempting to `UNION` two `SELECT` queries which output a different number of columns, and presumably, different data types - this is invalid.

I imagine that you are actually looking to do this:

```sql
select 
    student.idno,
    person.lastname,
    person.firstname,
    student.class,
    student.major,
    student.gpa,
    enrollment.offerno,
    enrollment.grade
from
    (
        student inner join person 
        on student.idno = person.idno
    )
    inner join enrollment 
    on student.idno = enrollment.idno
where
    student.class = 'JR'
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Now I'm trying to change this to be able to pull from multiple tables and I can seem to figure anything out. When I run this code, it tells me it can't find the table or query. If I run each section alone, it works just fine. I need to pull some info from 4 tables...

Comment: @JaredHammel Please edit your question if you wish to include additional information, or start a new question if your question is about something else.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you.